# Combine two queries from 1 table, 1 to Many

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following queries

```
select
o.increment_id, 
o.customer_id, 
round(o.base_grand_total * o.base_to_global_rate,2) as revGBP,
DATE_FORMAT(o.created_at, '01/%m/%Y') as 'MonthofOrder',
from 
hephaestus.sales_flat_order as o
Where  
o.status in ('complete', 'processing')
and
o.customer_email is not null
;
```

This extracts every order placed at my company

```
|increment id | Customer ID | revGBP | MonthofOrder | 
-----------------------------------------------------
| 123456     | 1            | 100    | 1-8-2014     |
-----------------------------------------------------
|123         | 1            | 200    |1-9-2014      |
----------------------------------------------------- 
|1234        | 2            | 250    |1-6-2014      |
-----------------------------------------------------
|123213      | 1            | 50     |1-7-2014      |
-----------------------------------------------------
|1235657     | 3            | 200    |1-9-2014      |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

My second query

```
select  
o.customer_ID as 'Email',
date_format(max(o.created_at), '01-%m-%Y') as 'LastOrderMonth',
sum(round((o.base_grand_total * o.base_to_global_rate),2)) as 'Rev GBP',
date_format(min(o.created_at), '01-%m-%Y')  as 'monthCustCreated',
count(o.increment_id) as 'CountOfOrders'
from    
hephaestus.sales_flat_order as o
where
status in ('complete', 'processing')
and
o.customer_ID is not null
group by 
o.customer_ID
;
```

This gives a top level view of customers spend so the output would look like

```
|Customer id |LastOrderMonth| revGBP |MonthCustCreated|CountOfOrders|
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|1           |1-9-2014      |350     |1-7-2014        | 3           |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|2           |1-6-2014      |250     |1-6-2014        | 1           |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|3           |1-9-2014      |200     |1-9-2014        | 1           |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The data is coming from the same table, I want to combine them, so I get the complete order table and then the customer summary attached to each row, I know this will bring in duplicate data when the customer ID matches but this is expected.

To be honest I am not a MySQL bod, so any help would be greatly appriciated.

Thanking anyone who can help in advance.

Comment: Do a LEFT JOIN on customer_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you asked for, but I think you would want to further aggregate this result set by GROUP BY customer_id to roll up the joined table. If that is the case, then simply add GROUP BY o.customer_id.

```
SELECT
  o.increment_id, 
  o.customer_id, 
  b.LastOrderMonth,
  ROUND(o.base_grand_total * o.base_to_global_rate,2) as revGBP,
  DATE_FORMAT(o.created_at, '01/%m/%Y') as 'MonthofOrder',
  b.monthCustCreated,
  b.CountOfOrders
FROM 
  sales_flat_order as o
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT  
      customer_id,
      date_format(MAX(created_at), '01-%m-%Y') as 'LastOrderMonth',
      sum(round((base_grand_total * base_to_global_rate),2)) as 'Rev GBP',
      date_format(MIN(created_at), '01-%m-%Y')  as 'monthCustCreated',
      COUNT(increment_id) as 'CountOfOrders'
    FROM    
      sales_flat_order
    WHERE
      status in ('complete', 'processing')
    AND
      customer_ID IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY 
      customer_ID
) b ON o.customer_id = b.customer_id
WHERE  
  o.status in ('complete', 'processing')
AND
  o.customer_email IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

My naive sugestion is

```
select
    *
from (<your first query>) as one
inner join (<your second query>) as two
on one.customer_id = two.customer_id;
```

There are a lot of performance improvement that could be made over this, however, with more thorough refactoring.